# How to make multiple UITableViewCells communicate/interact with each other?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, delegates, uiscrollview

I have several cells in a `UITableview`, each with their own `UIScrollView`. When a user scrolls in one of the cells I would like all of the other cells to follow. Is there any way to create this kind of interaction by passing the `contentOffset` to the other cells?

I'm thinking delegation but so far I can't get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite easy. Just implement the [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) method `scrollViewDidScroll:` in your viewController and there you set the contentOffset of all other cells. Make your viewController the delegate of the scrollview in each cell and you are done.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyFancyCell";
    MyFancyCell *cell = (MyFancyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.scrollView.delegate = self; // actually you would do this in the storyboard or inside (cell == nil) if you don't use storyboard
    // configure cell    
    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    if (scrollView == self.tableView) {
        // each tableView is a UIScrollView too. 
        // they will call this method which will lead to strange results if you change your cells scrollView.
        // just ignore the scroll events of the tableView
        return;
    }
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    for (MyFancyCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        cell.scrollView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
you could forward the delegate calls back to the cell, like this:

```
for (MyFancyCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    cell.scrollView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
    [cell scrollViewDidScroll:cell.scrollView];
}
```

or an imho better way. Make the viewController a delegate of the cell and in the scrollViewDidScoll method inside the cell you tell the delegate (viewController) that the contentOffset has changed so that the view controller updates the cells.

```
// MyFancyCell.h
@protocol MyFancyCellDelegate 
- (void)fancyCell:(MyFancyCell *)cell didChangeContentOffset:(CGPoint)offset;
@end
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyFancyCellDelegate> delegate;

// MyFancyCell.m

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     // do your work here
     [self.delegate fancyCell:self didChangeContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
}

// ViewController.m

- (void)fancyCell:(MyFancyCell *)cell didChangeContentOffset:(CGPoint)offset {
    for (MyFancyCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        cell.scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyFancyCell";
    MyFancyCell *cell = (MyFancyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.delegate = self;
    // configure
}
```

Comment: This works, the only problem is that I _also_ need to make UITableViewCell the delegate of the scroll view. I know an object can't have 2 delegates, so would you recommend calling the delegate method's again on each *cell* though my viewController?

Comment: I made an edit to show two possible ways. The second way is probably cleaner because you don't have to forward all delegate methods to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could synchronize among cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. For any change in one cell, you can call `reloadData` of the tableView, or reload only selected cells by calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation would be perfect.  You could pass a content offset to every table view, and have them all be each other's delegates (remember, that #importing in the .h will sometimes create an infinite loop, so just create categories in the .m file and do your #importing there).